# Consume from Kafka and send to Druid issue

Tags: druid

I have a Java application that supposed to read from Kafka, do some magic and send the data to Druid.

I have Kafka workers threads (about 15 per topic) that consume the data to from Kafka and eventually send it to Druid using Tranquillity.

This is the problem:
If I work with one thread - all is fine. If I work with more than one I get exceptions.

I tried working the following way:

1. Spring Druid service with several Tranquillity objects.
2. No Spring, Just create several Tranquillity objects for each thread.

I thought it might be concurrency issue.

When I say "several Tranquillity" I mean that I am sending the data to different tables.

I get :

```
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: List(package nio, package nio, package nio, package nio, package nio, package nio, package nio)
at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.suchThat(Symbols.scala:1678) ~[scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar!/:na]
at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:44) ~[scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar!/:na]
at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:40) ~[scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar!/:na]
at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:61) ~[scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar!/:na]
at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.staticModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:72) ~[scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar!/:na]
at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.staticClass(Mirrors.scala:119) ~[scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar!/:na]
at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.staticClass(Mirrors.scala:21) ~[scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar!/:na]
at com.metamx.tranquility.druid.DruidBeams$$anonfun$1$$typecreator3$1.apply(DruidBeams.scala:166) ~[tranquility-core_2.10-0.8.2.jar!/:0.8.2]
at scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$WeakTypeTagImpl.tpe$lzycompute(TypeTags.scala:231) ~[scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar!/:na]
at scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$WeakTypeTagImpl.tpe(TypeTags.scala:231) ~[scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar!/:na]
at scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$TypeTag$class.equals(TypeTags.scala:256) ~[scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar!/:na]
at scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$TypeTagImpl.equals(TypeTags.scala:291) ~[scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar!/:na]
at com.metamx.tranquility.druid.DruidBeams$$anonfun$1.apply(DruidBeams.scala:166) ~[tranquility-core_2.10-0.8.2.jar!/:0.8.2]
at com.metamx.tranquility.druid.DruidBeams$$anonfun$1.apply(DruidBeams.scala:152) ~[tranquility-core_2.10-0.8.2.jar!/:0.8.2]
at com.metamx.tranquility.druid.DruidBeams$.fromConfigInternal(DruidBeams.scala:341) ~[tranquility-core_2.10-0.8.2.jar!/:0.8.2]
at com.metamx.tranquility.druid.DruidBeams$.fromConfig(DruidBeams.scala:204) ~[tranquility-core_2.10-0.8.2.jar!/:0.8.2]
at com.metamx.tranquility.druid.DruidBeams$.fromConfig(DruidBeams.scala:123) ~[tranquility-core_2.10-0.8.2.jar!/:0.8.2]
at com.metamx.tranquility.druid.DruidBeams.fromConfig(DruidBeams.scala) ~[tranquility-core_2.10-0.8.2.jar!/:0.8.2]
at com.cooladata.etl.rt.connector.DruidConnector.registerSender(DruidConnector.java:57) 
at com.cooladata.etl.rt.util.DruidUtil.emmitEvent(DruidUtil.java:26)
```

Answer (score 0):

what I will suggest is taking other pay. First of all, you should know that tranquility drops events which are older than some specified period of time, as I remember one hour by default. In case you care only for recent events it is ok. 
Since you already have Kafka I would suggest you push processed data back to Kafka and use either Tranquility or [Kafka indexer service](http://druid.io/docs/latest/development/extensions-core/kafka-ingestion.html) to send data to Druid. Benefits of this approach are that not only Druid but other services can use this data. Also, in contrast to Tranquility Kafka indexer service does not drop any event.